# Error using Github actions with git clang-format

Tags: github, action, clang-format

Whenever a pull request to main is created, I want an action to check that the code follows our format guidelines for the repo.

Unfortunately im having trouble integrating this since the command keeps returning errors.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  clang_format_check:
    name: Check Clang Format
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Set up clang-format
        run: sudo apt-get install clang-format
        
      - name: Get commit ID of main branch
        run: |
          MAIN_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse main)
          echo "Commit ID of main branch: $MAIN_COMMIT"
          
      - name: Check code formatting
        run: |
          git clang-format --style=firmware/.clang-format --diff $MAIN_COMMIT..HEAD '*.cpp' '*.h'
          
      - name: Check for changes
        id: check_changes
        run: |
          git diff --exit-code || (echo "Code is not formatted properly. Please run clang-format and commit the changes." && exit 1)
          
      - name: Complete
        if: steps.check_changes.outcome == 'success'
        run: echo "Code is properly formatted."
```

On my windows pc, git rev-parse main works fine but on github action I keep getting errors:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this action step where you don't need to install it as linux command https://github.com/marketplace/actions/clang-format-code-formatter-with-ubuntu20-04

Comment: *git rev-parse main works fine but on github action I keep getting errors* You don't seem to push the branch `main` yet.

Comment: @273K Thank you for your response. I am a total beginner when it comes to github actions. I am not sure what you mean by push the branch main yet. The main branch is our default branch on github. I am trying to get it to run git clang-format to only update between the current branch's commit & main (where we are trying to merge to)

Comment: The error is clearly saying there is no branch `name` in the remote repo.

Comment: *to run git clang-format to only update between the current branch's commit & main* This is also your mistake. PRs can merge to any branch, not only main.

Comment: @273K I didnt know I had to tell it what main was since it is like the default branch in the repo. I added this line:

```name: Fetch main branch
        run: git fetch origin main:main```
Now I am able to find the latest main commit but it still says that my PR has no file changes when it does so I guess I have more digging to do, thanks again

Comment: Did you have a look at whether all previous steps ran successfully? I see the command `sudo apt-get install clang-format` asking for input. If you want to run install commands in an action, you should probably add the `-y` flag to make it non-interactive: `sudo apt-get install clang-format -y`.

Comment: @FelixSeifert Yeah all the previous steps work correctly and by doing git clang -h it properly shows how to use it. But despite making changes in the PR, it keeps saying that there are no modified files when there are. Not sure what to do